# ReactJs - Insert a new css class on element when a especific NavLink is active

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this app. Everything is workin successfully except what I wrote in this post title.

```
class PortfolioMenu extends Component {
  isActive= (match, location) => {
    if (match) {
     if (document.querySelector('.portfolio-menu')){
     document.querySelector('.portfolio-menu').className += " new-classjs";
     }
    }
    return match;
  };

  render(){   
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div class="wrapper2">
            <div class="wrapper-portfolio">
              <Route exact path='/portfolio' render={() => <Intro />} />
              <Route exact path='/portfolio/casas' render={() => <Casas />} />               
            </div>
            <nav>
              <ul className="portfolio-menu">
                <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" isActive={this.isActive} exact to="/portfolio">• introdução</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" exact to="/portfolio/casas">• casas</NavLink></li>

              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
  }


export default PortfolioMenu
```

How can you see in the code above, I have this react function that detect if some page is active. This function is working successfully. When I type `console.log(page detected)` in its body it shows the result

```
isActive= (match, location) => {
    if (match) {
     if (document.querySelector('.portfolio-menu')){
     document.querySelector('.portfolio-menu').className += " new-classjs";
     }
    }
    return match;
```

So the root of the issue is what happen in this function body in this especific case isn't working. I would like to sum the 'new-classjs' besides 'portfolio-menu' class resulting:  `<ul className="portfolio-menu new-classjs"">`. How can I solve it?

Comment: Consider writing this without any DOM lookups, might save yourself a headache

Comment: I would like only to add a new class in the 'portfolio-menu' only when a specific page is active

Comment: I headed the app and i see that it only works when I click in menu. When the page opens in the first time it donesn't work. i did a test with this body function
isActive= (match, location) => {
    if (match) {
     if (document.querySelector('.portfolio-menu')){
     document.querySelector('.portfolio-menu').style.color = "red"
     }
    }
    return match;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep a state property for the portfolio class and set it accordingly from the `isActive` method.

```js
class PortfolioMenu extends Component {
  state = {
    portfolioClass: ""
  };

  isActive = (match, location) => {
    const { portfolioClass } = this.state;
    const newClass = match ? "new-classjs" : "";
    if (newClass !== portfolioClass)
      this.setState({ portfolioClass: newClass });
    return match;
  };

  render() {
    const { portfolioClass } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div class="wrapper2">
            <div class="wrapper-portfolio">
              <Route exact path="/portfolio" render={() => <Intro />} />
              <Route exact path="/portfolio/casas" render={() => <Casas />} />
            </div>
            <nav>
              <ul className={`portfolio-menu ${portfolioClass}`}>
                <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" isActive={this.isActive} exact to="/portfolio">• introdução</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" exact to="/portfolio/casas">• casas</NavLink></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/p91xk60p6j